How to load kernels from source?
I'm having issue with my Internet connection and so I want to try different kernels. I'm not able to use kernel manager so I downloaded the tar files from a different machine and now I want to load these into boot directory to test them.
For the record, I downloaded the tarballs from this website. https://www.kernel.org/
Now I want to know how to load them as bootable kernels. How do I go about doing this?

Have you looked at any docs?? eg. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel or https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile    Any instructions you receive on this site currently will assume older package versions (used in compile to noble which is still off-topic) thus you'll need to adapt for your currently beta product.
